# How to install league/OAuth2-client through composer

Tags: oauth-2.0, composer-php

I am getting an error while trying to install league/oauth2-client through composer on ubuntu with newest curl and openssl libraries combined with newest php release:

```
$ composer require league/oauth2-client
Using version ^0.12.1 for league/oauth2-client
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for league/oauth2-client 1.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by league/oauth2-client[1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: league/oauth2-client[0.12.1, 1.0.x-dev].
- Installation request for league/oauth2-client ^0.12.1 -> satisfiable by league/oauth2-client[0.12.1].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

could not find any hint through searching for answers so far. Thank you in advance for any heop on this!

cotent of composer.json

```
$ cat composer.json 
{
    "name": "league/oauth2-client",
    "description": "OAuth 2.0 Client Library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "~1.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "~0.9",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.0",
        "satooshi/php-coveralls": "0.6.*",
        "jakub-onderka/php-parallel-lint": "0.8.*"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "oauth",
        "oauth2",
        "authorization",
        "authentication",
        "idp",
        "identity",
        "sso",
        "single sign on"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Alex Bilbie",
            "email": "hello@alexbilbie.com",
            "homepage": "http://www.alexbilbie.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "League\\OAuth2\\Client\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "League\\OAuth2\\Client\\Test\\": "test/src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your composer.json?

Comment: this is a standard installation, just checked out of git repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using composer wrong. Try running `composer install`

From the composer documentation:

> The require command adds new packages to the composer.json file from
>   the current directory. If no file exists one will be created on the
>   fly.
>
> The install command reads the composer.json file from the current
>   directory, resolves the dependencies, and installs them into vendor.

So if the composer.json is that of league/oauth2-client, just run `composer install`

If you want league/oauth2-client to be added as a dependency for some other package, run `composer require league/oauth2-client`

Comment: thank you. that worked! I don't understand why the readme tells otherwise: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client   Install

Via Composer

$ composer require league/oauth2-client

Comment: Normally you wouldn't use the oauth2-client alone. I would be part of an application and hence a dependency. I think that is what the author meant

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this installing  knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle  first. So you need to follow this order:

```
composer require knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle
composer require league/oauth2-client
composer require league/oauth2-facebook
```

This is my composer.json file after installing:

```
{
"knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle": "^1.9",
"league/oauth2-client": "^2.2",
"league/oauth2-facebook": "^2.0"
}
```

Hope it helps